# Dynamic size pseudo element CSS without JavaScript

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

In front of my title, I've added a pseudo element to make the background slanted. The title can be wrapped which results in a bigger height. I've been trying to make the pseudo element adapt to the height of the title but without luck so far.

I've used all kind of combinations with flex / (inline)block and absolute etc. But I just can't seem to get it to work.

I need it to be fully responsive and without the use of JavaScript.

---

The image shown below is when the title consist of only one line.

- Orange: background of title wrapper
- Purple: the pseudo element placed in front of the title
- Green: the title

[image: single-line]

---

When I resize the screen and the title wraps up it shows up like this:

- As shown in the image, the purple element is too small

[image]

---

If I change the z-index, you can see the purple element:
[image]

---

And the actual result I'm looking for. The purple element should be at the left side of the title at all times, covering up the full height of the title, showing the slanted side.
[image]

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
}

.title::before {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  content: '';
  transform: skew(-22.5deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}

.title span {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <span>Some text for the title</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a solution that uses SVG vectors instead of pseudo elements to achieve the effect that you seek.

You can resize height of the `.title` element and it will remain consistent.

```css
.title {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.module_title span {
  background-color: green;
}

.title span {
  padding: 5px 60px;
  color: white;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>z</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="/mysite/static/.other/z.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="title">
      <svg class="orange" width="80" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polygon id="cover" points="0,100 0,0 50,0" style="fill: orange"></polygon>
      </svg>
      <svg class="purple" width="80" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <polygon id="cover" points="30,0 60,0 30,100 0,100" style="fill: purple"></polygon>
      </svg>
      <span>Some text for the title</span>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rob. It seems using SVG is the only way of fixing this. Still trying things out and when it succeeds I'll accept this answer so in the meantime I might get other solutions which doesn't need SVG.

Comment: @HennyLee What else are you still trying to achieve? Do you really want to do it with pseudo elements?

Answer (score 0):

Use the inherit value for height in your pseudo element, like this:

```
.title:before {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: inherit;
  width: 50px;
  content: '';
  transform: skew(-22.5deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I like @RobKwasowski's solution, this can be done without svg. Most of the styles are yours, but I don't use flex. Please observe the `.title` has `position:relative;overflow:hidden;` The `position:relative;`is because I want the `before` to be `position:absolute` The `overflow:hidden;` is to cut off the extra bits of span.

I hope it helps.

```css
.title {
  background-color: orange;
  padding:0 0 0 3em;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.title::before {  
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  content: '';
  transform: skew(-22.5deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}

.title span {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:2em 0 2em 5em;
  width:100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <span>Some text for the title<br>Some text for the title<br>Some text for the title</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I've tried this already and the purple bar will be on a fixed position so when the text wraps (increasing the height of green) the purple bar will have the same effect as my examples.

Comment: There is also a gap between the orange and purple at the top where the green background shows through.

Comment: @HennyLee I've changed the padding for the `.title` and now you can have one two or three lines without the green gap